# Master-Detail with jqGrid+Asp.Net MVC and transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, transactions, master-detail

I'm coming from the delphi world and I want to make a master/detail interface, like Order and Products.
I already made actions to display the data using fields and a jqGrid. What I want know is how make possible to add lines, edit or remove them, but, just make the changes in db when the user confirm the changes in the master.
On delphi I would use a TClientDataSet with all the in memory changes and just after the confirmation would execute them inside a transaction like:
`BEGIN

Master.Post

FOREACH Line IN Lines Line.Post

COMMIT`

So in resume, I don't know how keep in memory the array of lines in the grid and how send them back to server to commit.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of the changes client side, perhaps using some hidden fields and/or form fields in your grid.  When a line is deleted (that previously existed in the db), you'll need to add it's id to a field containing lines to delete.  Lines that are added need to have associated form fields containing their data.  When the master is committed you roll the whole set of fields up into a POST and send that back to the server.

Using LINQ to SQL, you'd create a data context, get the master object, then delete the related objects (from the hidden field of ids) that are so marked and create/add new related objects that didn't exist before taking the values from the appropriate form fields.  Then you'd do a `SubmitChanges` and all of the statements would be executed within a single transaction.